# My minimum section isn't showing the real minimum

Tags: c, max, average, min

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
float a[100],sum=0.0,avg,havg[100],min,max;
int i;
for(i=0; i!=-1;i++){
    printf("Enter number : ");
    scanf("%f",&a[i]);
    max = a[0];
    min = a[0];
    sum+=a[i];
    avg= sum/(i+1);
    havg[i]=avg/2;
    printf("Loop %d Summation : %.0f ",i,sum);
    printf("Half of Avg. : %.2f \n",havg[i]);
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
       if (a[i]>max) {
           max = a[i];
       }
       if (a[i]<min) {
           min = a[i];
       }
    }
    if(a[i]>havg[i-1]&&i!=0){
       break;
    }
}
printf("---Data Complete---\n");
printf("Max: %.0f\n", max);
printf("Min: %.0f\n", min);
```

The output here is:

> Enter number : 24
>
> Loop 0 Summation : 24 Half of Avg. : 12.00
>
> Enter number : 12
>
> Loop 1 Summation : 36 Half of Avg. : 9.00
>
> Enter number : -5
>
> Loop 2 Summation : 31 Half of Avg. : 5.17
>
> Enter number : 9
>
> Loop 3 Summation : 40 Half of Avg. : 5.00
>
> ---Data Complete---
>
> Max: 24
>
> Min: 9

I look up for the min and max in the array on google already. I think I mess something up:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
float a[100],sum=0.0,avg,havg[100],min=0.0,max=0.0;
int i;
for(i=0; i!=-1;i++){
    printf("Enter number : ");
    scanf("%f",&a[i]);
    max = a[0];
    min = a[0];
    sum+=a[i];
    avg= sum/(i+1);
    havg[i]=avg/2;
    printf("Loop %d Summation : %.0f ",i+1,sum);
    printf("Half of Avg. : %.2f \n",havg[i]);
    if (a[i]>max){
      max = a[i];
        }
    if (a[i]<min){
      min = a[i];
        }
    if(a[i]>havg[i-1]&&i!=0){
       break;
    }
}
printf("---Data Complete---\n");
printf("Max: %.0f\n", max);
printf("Min: %.0f\n", min);
}
```

So now I test with different number (start with negative first)

```
Enter number : -10

Loop 1 Summation : -10 Half of Avg. : -5.00 

Enter number : -90 

Loop 2 Summation : -100 Half of Avg. : -25.00 

Enter number : 30

Loop 3 Summation : -70 Half of Avg. : -11.67 

---Data Complete---

Max: 30

Min: -10
```

This is really confusing

Comment: How do you know that `for(i=0; i!=-1;i++)` does not break the arrays' bounds? And you have bad indexing on the first iteration with `havg[i-1]`. And you aren't using `j` in the `for(int j=0; j<i; j++)` loop, but doing the same stuff `i` times.

Comment: I know this is a bad one but I want unlimited input until it meets the condition of (The last input is more than last half average) is there any other ways. Thank you.

Comment: @NutGrimmir `I want unlimited input` you can use dynamic arrays that may be reallocated if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please move the `min` and `max` initialisation, which is done in every loop

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    float a[100],sum=0.0,avg,havg[100],min=0.0,max=0.0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i!=-1;i++){
        printf("Enter number : ");
        scanf("%f",&a[i]);
        sum+=a[i];
        avg= sum/(i+1);
        havg[i]=avg/2;
        printf("Loop %d Summation : %.0f ",i+1,sum);
        printf("Half of Avg. : %.2f \n",havg[i]);
        if(i == 0) {
            max = a[0];             // moved to here
            min = a[0];
        }
        else {
            if (a[i]>max){
                max = a[i];
            }
            if (a[i]<min){
                min = a[i];
            }
            if(a[i]>havg[i-1]) {    // moved this too
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("---Data Complete---\n");
    printf("Max: %.0f\n", max);
    printf("Min: %.0f\n", min);
}
```

Program output:

```
Enter number : -10
Loop 1 Summation : -10 Half of Avg. : -5.00
Enter number : -90
Loop 2 Summation : -100 Half of Avg. : -25.00
Enter number : 30
Loop 3 Summation : -70 Half of Avg. : -11.67
---Data Complete---
Max: 30
Min: -90
```

Comment: Just found out after reviewing the code again. Thanks!
How can I simplify the code to look a bit less messy?

Comment: Why do you need arrays? You only need remember the previous average, and now the array length problem goes away. The arrays would be more useful if you structure the code to have a different ending condition, enter all the data first, and then compute the stats in another loop.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this one out. I decided to put it in the beginning of the loop.